# NPM: How do I troubleshoot if a file inside of a package cannot be found?

Tags: npm, package, next.js, node-modules, react-tsx

How do I troubleshoot if a file inside of a package cannot be found?

```
./node_modules/react-pdf-highlighter/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css
Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'images/loading-icon.gif'
```

I am trying to use the react-pdf-highlighter in a nextjs project.

I have tried adding file-loader for .gif in my webpack.

It seems like the issue is inside of the react-pdf-highlighter, since it is inside of its node_modules.

Of course I would like to know the reply to this specific problem, but even more:
How do I approach this type of issue? Are there steps that can be taken to figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Image must be in public. To access it in jsx type:

```
/images/loading-icon.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to troubleshoot `"not found"` error

You need to go to your `node_modules` folder and check your package for the existing file. If your file `pdf_viewer.css` exists, just change the placing of this file to, for example, your root.

After, what I see, you have no file called `loading-icon.gif`in `images/loading-icon.gif'`, add it to the `images` folder. Also check your `pdf_viewer.css`, I am sure your gif is loaded somewhere there.